# An unknown Subversion error occurred. (code = 210002)

Tags: svn

I'm new to SVN so I don't know where to start..

I setup svn via basic apt-get and it used to work and all of the sudden stopped. I can see svnserve in ps -A and am using svn+ssh and Versions for mac.

edit - I've spent a good number of hours googling this on the web and trying solutions with no avail.

Comment: Are the versions of SVN the same on both your server and your client?  I've seen that cause problems before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had created a "dump" of a repo and imported that dump onto another server. Then I reused my same local repo so that I didn't have to re-download but it looks like the .svn info folders thought it was the old repo and caused some problems.